# Combobox scrolling the page on using arrow keys ExtJs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs

I have a simple risk assessment matrix built using ExtJs. When I use arrow keys to select from the list of the combobox it scrolls the page automatically. I face this problem only when I run it in Chrome. In Inter Explorer it works fine. So I opened the console and saw the following error:-

> Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

So I copied my code to [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2hdc) and it works fine there but here's a link to my actual [webpage](http://159.65.173.161/extTest.html) hosted on a server. Please navigate to the assessment tab. Here's the code to my matrix:-

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
     name: 'myContainer',
     id: 'myContainer',
     renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
     items: [{
         title: 'Assessment',
         name: 'assessmentPanel',
         id: 'assessmentPanel',
         layout: {
             type: 'table',
             tdAttrs: {
                 style: {
                     border: '1px solid #ccc'
                 }
             },
             columns: 5
         },
         defaults: {
             bodyStyle: 'padding:40px',
         },
         items: [{
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             cellCls: 'gray'
         }, {
             html: '<b>Consequence</b>'
         }, {
             html: '<b>Likelihood</b>'
         }, {
             width: 15,
             border: false,
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             cellCls: 'gray'
         }, {
             html: '<b>Risk</b>'
         }, {
             html: '<b>Service Interruption</b>'
         }, {
             xtype: 'combobox',
             name: 'assessment1',
             id: 'assessment1',
             cellCls: 'green',
             cls: 'bg-trasparent',
             value: '1',
             hideTrigger: true,
             listeners: {
                 select: function(combo, records) {
                     var Myvalue = this.getValue();
                     assessRisk();
                     if (Myvalue == "1") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'green');

                     } else if (Myvalue == "2") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'yellow');

                     } else if (Myvalue == "3") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'orange');

                     } else if (Myvalue == "4") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'red');

                     }
                 }
             },
             queryMode: 'local',
             width: 130,
             displayField: 'text',
             valueField: 'value',
             editable: false,
             store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                 data: [{
                     text: 'Minor',
                     value: '1'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Moderate',
                     value: '2'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Major',
                     value: '3'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Severe',
                     value: '4'
                 }]
             })
         }, {
             xtype: 'combobox',
             name: 'assessment7',
             cellCls: 'green',
             cls: 'bg-trasparent',
             id: 'assessment7',
             value: '1',
             hideTrigger: true,
             listeners: {
                 select: function(combo, records) {
                     var Myvalue = this.getValue();
                     assessRisk();
                     if (Myvalue == "1") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'green');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "2") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'yellow');

                     } else if (Myvalue == "3") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'orange');

                     } else if (Myvalue == "4") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'red');
                     }
                 }
             },
             queryMode: 'local',
             width: 130,
             displayField: 'text',
             valueField: 'value',
             editable: false,
             store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                 data: [{
                     text: 'Remote',
                     value: '1'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Possible',
                     value: '2'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Likely',
                     value: '3'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Almost Certain',
                     value: '4'
                 }]
             })
         }, {
             width: 15,
             border: false,
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             cellCls: 'gray'
         }, {
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             name: 'risk1',
             id: 'risk1',
             value: 'Low',
             cellCls: 'green',
             fieldCls: 'boldify',
         }, {
             html: '<b>Revenue Growth</b>'
         }, {
             xtype: 'combobox',
             name: 'assessment2',
             id: 'assessment2',
             cellCls: 'green',
             cls: 'bg-trasparent',
             value: '1',
             width: 130,
             hideTrigger: true,
             listeners: {
                 select: function(combo, records) {
                     var Myvalue = this.getValue();
                     assessRisk();
                     if (Myvalue == "1") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'green');

                     } else if (Myvalue == "2") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'yellow');

                     } else if (Myvalue == "3") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'orange');

                     } else if (Myvalue == "4") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'red');
                     }
                 }
             },
             queryMode: 'local',
             displayField: 'text',
             valueField: 'value',
             editable: false,
             store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                 data: [{
                     text: 'Minor',
                     value: '1'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Moderate',
                     value: '2'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Major',
                     value: '3'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Severe',
                     value: '4'
                 }]
             })
         }, {
             xtype: 'combobox',
             name: 'assessment8',
             id: 'assessment8',
             cellCls: 'green',
             cls: 'bg-trasparent',
             value: '1',
             hideTrigger: true,
             listeners: {
                 select: function(combo, records) {
                     var Myvalue = this.getValue();
                     assessRisk();
                     if (Myvalue == "1") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'green');

                     } else if (Myvalue == "2") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'yellow');

                     } else if (Myvalue == "3") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'orange');

                     } else if (Myvalue == "4") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'red');
                     }
                 }
             },
             queryMode: 'local',
             width: 130,
             displayField: 'text',
             valueField: 'value',
             editable: false,
             store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                 data: [{
                     text: 'Remote',
                     value: '1'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Possible',
                     value: '2'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Likely',
                     value: '3'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Almost Certain',
                     value: '4'
                 }]
             })
         }, {
             width: 15,
             border: false,
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             cellCls: 'gray'
         }, {
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             name: 'risk2',
             id: 'risk2',
             value: 'Low',
             cellCls: 'green',
             fieldCls: 'boldify',
         }, {
             html: '<b>Reputation</b>'
         }, {
             xtype: 'combobox',
             name: 'assessment3',
             id: 'assessment3',
             cellCls: 'green',
             cls: 'bg-trasparent',
             value: '1',
             width: 130,
             hideTrigger: true,
             listeners: {
                 select: function(combo, records) {
                     var Myvalue = this.getValue();
                     assessRisk();
                     if (Myvalue == "1") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'green');

                     } else if (Myvalue == "2") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'yellow');

                     } else if (Myvalue == "3") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'orange');

                     } else if (Myvalue == "4") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'red');
                     }
                 }
             },
             queryMode: 'local',
             displayField: 'text',
             valueField: 'value',
             editable: false,
             store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                 data: [{
                     text: 'Minor',
                     value: '1'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Moderate',
                     value: '2'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Major',
                     value: '3'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Severe',
                     value: '4'
                 }]
             })
         }, {
             xtype: 'combobox',
             name: 'assessment9',
             id: 'assessment9',
             cellCls: 'green',
             cls: 'bg-trasparent',
             value: '1',
             hideTrigger: true,
             listeners: {
                 select: function(combo, records) {
                     var Myvalue = this.getValue();
                     assessRisk();
                     if (Myvalue == "1") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'green');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "2") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'yellow');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "3") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'orange');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "4") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'red');
                     }
                 }
             },
             queryMode: 'local',
             width: 130,
             displayField: 'text',
             valueField: 'value',
             editable: false,
             store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                 data: [{
                     text: 'Remote',
                     value: '1'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Possible',
                     value: '2'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Likely',
                     value: '3'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Almost Certain',
                     value: '4'
                 }]
             })
         }, {
             width: 15,
             border: false,
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             cellCls: 'gray'
         }, {
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             name: 'risk3',
             id: 'risk3',
             value: 'Low',
             cellCls: 'green',
             fieldCls: 'boldify',
         }, {
             html: '<b>Legal and Compliance</b>'
         }, {
             xtype: 'combobox',
             name: 'assessment4',
             id: 'assessment4',
             cellCls: 'green',
             cls: 'bg-trasparent',
             value: '1',
             width: 130,
             // scroll: false,
             hideTrigger: true,
             listeners: {
                 select: function(combo, records) {
                     var Myvalue = this.getValue();
                     assessRisk();
                     if (Myvalue == "1") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'green');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "2") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'yellow');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "3") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'orange');

                     } else if (Myvalue == "4") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'red');
                     }
                 }
             },
             queryMode: 'local',
             displayField: 'text',
             valueField: 'value',
             editable: false,
             store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                 data: [{
                     text: 'Minor',
                     value: '1'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Moderate',
                     value: '2'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Major',
                     value: '3'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Severe',
                     value: '4'
                 }]
             })
         }, {
             xtype: 'combobox',
             name: 'assessment10',
             id: 'assessment10',
             cellCls: 'green',
             cls: 'bg-trasparent',
             value: '1',
             hideTrigger: true,
             listeners: {
                 select: function(combo, records) {
                     var Myvalue = this.getValue();
                     assessRisk();
                     if (Myvalue == "1") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'green');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "2") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'yellow');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "3") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'orange');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "4") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'red');
                     }

                 }
             },
             queryMode: 'local',
             width: 130,
             displayField: 'text',
             valueField: 'value',
             editable: false,
             store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                 data: [{
                     text: 'Remote',
                     value: '1'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Possible',
                     value: '2'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Likely',
                     value: '3'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Almost Certain',
                     value: '4'
                 }]
             })
         }, {
             width: 15,
             border: false,
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             cellCls: 'gray'
         }, {
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             name: 'risk4',
             id: 'risk4',
             value: 'Low',
             cellCls: 'green',
             fieldCls: 'boldify',
         }, {
             html: '<b>Capital Items</b>'
         }, {
             xtype: 'combobox',
             name: 'assessment5',
             id: 'assessment5',
             cellCls: 'green',
             cls: 'bg-trasparent',
             value: '1',
             width: 130,
             hideTrigger: true,
             listeners: {
                 select: function(combo, records) {
                     var Myvalue = this.getValue();
                     assessRisk();
                     if (Myvalue == "1") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'green');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "2") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'yellow');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "3") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'orange');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "4") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'red');
                     }

                 }
             },
             queryMode: 'local',
             displayField: 'text',
             valueField: 'value',
             editable: false,
             store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                 data: [{
                     text: 'Minor',
                     value: '1'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Moderate',
                     value: '2'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Major',
                     value: '3'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Severe',
                     value: '4'
                 }]
             })
         }, {
             xtype: 'combobox',
             name: 'assessment11',
             id: 'assessment11',
             cellCls: 'green',
             cls: 'bg-trasparent',
             value: '1',
             hideTrigger: true,
             listeners: {
                 select: function(combo, records) {
                     var Myvalue = this.getValue();
                     assessRisk();
                     if (Myvalue == "1") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'green');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "2") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'yellow');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "3") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'orange');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "4") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'red');
                     }

                 }
             },
             queryMode: 'local',
             width: 130,
             displayField: 'text',
             valueField: 'value',
             editable: false,
             store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                 data: [{
                     text: 'Remote',
                     value: '1'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Possible',
                     value: '2'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Likely',
                     value: '3'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Almost Certain',
                     value: '4'
                 }]
             })
         }, {
             width: 15,
             border: false,
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             cellCls: 'gray'
         }, {
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             name: 'risk5',
             id: 'risk5',
             value: 'Low',
             cellCls: 'green',
             fieldCls: 'boldify',
         }, {
             html: '<b>Financial</b>'
         }, {
             xtype: 'combobox',
             name: 'assessment6',
             id: 'assessment6',
             cellCls: 'green',
             cls: 'bg-trasparent',
             value: '1',
             width: 130,
             //scroll: false,
             hideTrigger: true,
             listeners: {
                 select: function(combo, records) {
                     var Myvalue = this.getValue();
                     assessRisk();
                     if (Myvalue == "1") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'green');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "2") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'yellow');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "3") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'orange');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "4") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'red');
                     }

                 }
             },
             queryMode: 'local',
             displayField: 'text',
             valueField: 'value',
             editable: false,
             store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                 data: [{
                     text: 'Minor',
                     value: '1'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Moderate',
                     value: '2'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Major',
                     value: '3'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Severe',
                     value: '4'
                 }]
             })
         }, {
             xtype: 'combobox',
             name: 'assessment12',
             id: 'assessment12',
             cellCls: 'green',
             cls: 'bg-trasparent',
             value: '1',
             // scroll: false,
             hideTrigger: true,
             listeners: {
                 select: function(combo, records) {
                     var Myvalue = this.getValue();
                     assessRisk();
                     if (Myvalue == "1") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'green');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "2") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'yellow');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "3") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'orange');
                     } else if (Myvalue == "4") {
                         combo.el.up('td').setStyle('background', 'red');
                     }

                 }

             },
             queryMode: 'local',
             width: 130,
             displayField: 'text',
             valueField: 'value',
             editable: false,
             store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                 data: [{
                     text: 'Remote',
                     value: '1'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Possible',
                     value: '2'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Likely',
                     value: '3'
                 }, {
                     text: 'Almost Certain',
                     value: '4'
                 }]
             })
         }, {
             width: 15,
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             cellCls: 'gray'

         }, {
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             name: 'risk6',
             id: 'risk6',
             value: 'Low',
             cellCls: 'green',
             fieldCls: 'boldify',
         }, {
             height: 20,
             baseCls: 'gray'
         }, {
             height: 20,
             baseCls: 'gray'
         }, {
             height: 20,
             baseCls: 'gray'
         }, {
             width: 20,
             height: 20,
             baseCls: 'gray'
         }, {
             height: 20,
             id: 'test123',
             name: 'test123',
             baseCls: 'gray'
         }, {
             html: '<b>Highest Risk</b>'
         }, {
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             name: 'finalConsequence',
             id: 'finalConsequence',
             value: 'Minor',
             cellCls: 'green',
             fieldCls: 'boldify',
         }, {
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             name: 'finalLikelihood',
             id: 'finalLikelihood',
             value: 'Remote',
             cellCls: 'green',
             fieldCls: 'boldify',

         }, {
             width: 15,
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             cellCls: 'gray',
         }, {
             xtype: 'displayfield',
             name: 'finalRisk',
             id: 'finalRisk',
             value: 'Low',
             cellCls: 'green',
             fieldCls: 'boldify',
         }],
         buttons: [{
             text: 'Back',
             scale: 'medium',
             handler: function() {;
             }
         }, {
             text: 'Submit',
             formBind: true,
             scale: 'medium',
             disabled: true,
             handler: function() {}
         }]
     }]
 });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, in the extjs version that you using (6.0.0),  the combo is bubbling up the arrows keys events to the browser when the "editable" config is set to false, probably a bug.

The fiddle works because its set to the latest version of Extjs

One solution its to create a handler to the keydown event and stop the event propagation, first enable key events in the combo box, set:

```
enableKeyEvents: true
```

Create the function to handle arrow keys on keydown:

```
function  handleKeyUpDown(combo,e){ 
    if ((e.keyCode == 38)||(e.keyCode == 40)) {
       e.stopEvent();
    }
}
```

And set the combo listener:

```
keydown: handleKeyUpDown
```

I Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. I just changed my extjs version to 6.2.0 and it works